Azure Blob Storage (REST API): Cannot list blobs in container with curl using SAS token
I have been playing around with using the Azure Blob storage REST API for a few days now.
I can connect to the resource, list containers and also generate SAS tokens for any given container with no problems.
However, I am now having problems when trying to list the blobs within a container using the SAS token I have generated for the container.
With my generated SAS token I have tried the following curl command (taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs?tabs=microsoft-entra-id)
curl -X GET "https://dat3473spa01cfeMtest.blob.core.windows.net/90480397-91234697-218-test-dir01?restype=container&comp=list&?sv=2019-02-02&sr=c&sig=QlSozpknsTcR4frUK08%2FrcGaUGY893GzFN1Lyhl74Ao%3D&se=2024-10-24T07%3A50%3A11Z&sp=racwdl"

Where https://dat3473spa01cfeMtest.blob.core.windows.net is the blobServiceUri, 90480397-91234697-218-test-dir01 is the container name and ?sv=2019-02-02&sr=c&sig=QlSozpknsTcR4frUK08%2FrcGaUGY893GzFN1Lyhl74Ao%3D&se=2024-10-24T07%3A50%3A11Z&sp=racwdl is the SAS token I have generated for the container in a previous step.
When running the curl command I get the following error message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:d370a92d-301e-0082-34ee-25f845000000
Time:2024-10-24T08:30:24.7319888Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>

I assume the problem is related to the way I am specifying the SAS token in the curl command, but from the documentation on the previously mentioned website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs?tabs=microsoft-entra-id) I cannot see how to specify the SAS token correctly, if, indeed, this is the problem with my curl command.
I have also tried the following commands:
curl -X GET "https://dat3473spa01cfeMtest.blob.core.windows.net/90480397-91234697-218-test-dir01?restype=container&comp=list" -H "x-ms-version: 2025-01-05" -H "x-ms-date: Thu, 24 oct. 2024 08:29:07 GMT" -H "Authorization: ?sv=2019-02-02&sr=c&sig=QlSozpknsTcR4frUK08%2FrcGaUGY893GzFN1Lyhl74Ao%3D&se=2024-10-24T07%3A50%3A11Z&sp=racwdl"

curl -X GET "https://dat3473spa01cfeMtest.blob.core.windows.net/90480397-91234697-218-test-dir01?restype=container&comp=list" -H "x-ms-version: 2025-01-05" -H "x-ms-date: Thu, 24 oct. 2024 08:29:07 GMT" -H "Authorization: credential=?sv=2019-02-02&sr=c&sig=QlSozpknsTcR4frUK08%2FrcGaUGY893GzFN1Lyhl74Ao%3D&se=2024-10-24T07%3A50%3A11Z&sp=racwdl"

curl -X GET "https://dat3473spa01cfeMtest.blob.core.windows.net/90480397-91234697-218-test-dir01?restype=container&comp=list" -H "x-ms-version: 2025-01-05" -H "x-ms-date: Thu, 24 oct. 2024 08:29:07 GMT" -H "Authorization: credentials=?sv=2019-02-02&sr=c&sig=QlSozpknsTcR4frUK08%2FrcGaUGY893GzFN1Lyhl74Ao%3D&se=2024-10-24T07%3A50%3A11Z&sp=racwdl"

curl -X GET "https://dat3473spa01cfeMtest.blob.core.windows.net/90480397-91234697-218-test-dir01?restype=container&comp=list" -H "x-ms-version: 2025-01-05" -H "x-ms-date: Thu, 24 oct. 2024 08:29:07 GMT" -H "Authorization: token ?sv=2019-02-02&sr=c&sig=QlSozpknsTcR4frUK08%2FrcGaUGY893GzFN1Lyhl74Ao%3D&se=2024-10-24T07%3A50%3A11Z&sp=racwdl"

These all give the error:
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidAuthenticationInfo</Code>
    <Message>Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.
RequestId:79a74d3f-101e-0071-5bf0-255fd0000000
Time:2024-10-24T08:44:39.7753277Z</Message>
</Error>


Don't use two time ? in the url

Use only after container ?restype=container&comp=list& <sas token>

That's the solution! I removed the ? from the SAS token returned by my code. Many thanks @Venkatesan for your help.


Cannot list blobs in container with curl using SAS token.

I followed the same MS-Document,
I generate sas token from the portal.
Portal:

Now, You can use the below request format to get the list of blobs using cURL.
Request:
curl -X GET "https://venkat326123.blob.core.windows.net/test?restype=container&comp=list&sp=racwdli&st=2024-10-24T08:59:44Z&se=2024-10-24T16:59:44Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=redacted"

Output:

